# Make ajax script insert in dbase

Tags: ajax, insert, chat

I want to make these code insert in DBase in table chat; let's say, but I dont know how. I am bad at AJAX and I want to learn. Can you help me do it?Thank you very much.

Here is my table from DBase:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `legacy_chat` (
  `id` int(99) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chatter` int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `who` int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timesent` int(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msgtext` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rid` int(99) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `exposed` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

[codes](http://gtastorymods.com/testers/)

Comment: You need to make an PHP page that inserts values into the database, and use AJAX to send values to the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to create a php file that takes the information you wish to add/change/delete to/from the database. You will load that file using AJAX (or jQuery) via POST or GET with the info you wish to manipulate. You may also update the requesting page using the callback to notify the user that the action was or not successfully executed.

Have a look over the following tutorials which guide you step-by-step:

- [Infotuts.com](http://www.infotuts.com/crud-example-php-jquery-ajax/)
- [Programming-free](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/08/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-java-web.html)
- [CodeofNinja.com](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/06/php-crud-with-ajax-and-oop.html)